# Keeping a state of how many people watch a certain part of a video?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to make a kind of heatmap for video's. I have a little page where the same video plays 2 times. I already have a way to get the played parts out of the individual video's but now I should be able to aggregate the data to draw a graph to show wich part of the video was watched once, twice or not at all.

The example output is like this

```
played1 = [33,36][40,44][52,56]...
played2 = [31,35][42,46][55,58]...
```

the output should be that 31-33 was played once, 33-35 played twice, 35-36 played once, 36-40 wasn't played,...

I'm getting pretty close to a solution but there's something going wrong and I don't know what, this is the code I have:

```
function getPlayData(r,e){
var Played = 0;
var data = [];


if(r.played.length > 0){

    for(var i = 0; i < r.played.length; i ++){
        for(var j = 0; j < parseInt(r.duration); j ++ ){
            if(parseInt(r.played.start(i)) - j === 0){
                Played ++;
                data.push(j,Played);
            }
            else if(parseInt(r.played.end(i)) - j === 0){
                Played --;
                data.push(j,Played);
            }
        }
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < e.played.length; i ++){
        for(var k = 0; k < parseInt(e.duration); k ++){
            if(parseInt(e.played.start(i)) - k === 0){
                Played++;
                data.push(k,Played);
            }
            else if(parseInt(e.played.end(i)) - k === 0){
                Played--;
                data.push(k,Played);
            }
        }
    }
}
return data;
}
```

this should return an array with a timestamp and how many plays there were at that time but if both video's start at 0 only one view is recorded and the behaviour is overall not consistent. I'm still a beginner so sorry if I'm making an abvious mistake and thanks for all the help I can get!

[edit] I'm using the parseInt method because it's all floating point data and I've read a lot about floating point not being accurate so I wanted to get it working with integer's before I make it more accurate for floating point

Comment: Can you add some sample data for the 2 variables `r` and `e`?

Comment: the r,e variables are video objects loaded with hls js. if you go to this page http://dailymotion.github.io/hls.js/demo/ and click "toggle stats display" you can see at the bottom what's in those variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code to this

```
function getPlayData(r,e){
var Played = 0;
var data = [];


if(r.played.length > 0){

    for(var i = 0; i < r.played.length; i ++){
        for(var j = 0; j <= parseInt(r.duration); j ++ ){
            if(parseInt(r.played.start(i)) - j === 0){
                Played ++;
                data.push(j,Played);
            }
            if(parseInt(e.played.start(i)) - j === 0){
                Played++;
                data.push(j,Played);
            }
            if(parseInt(r.played.end(i)) - j === 0){
                Played --;
                data.push(j,Played);
            }
            if(parseInt(e.played.end(i)) - j === 0){
                Played--;
                data.push(j,Played);
            }
        }
    }
}
return data;
}
```

And it seems to work! Thanks anyway for anyone who read my post and tried to help!